# Upgrading Qt version to the latest

Tags: c++, qt, version, upgrade

hopefully everyone will be doing great.
I wanted to ask if the **existing version** of Qt (not Qt Creator) be **upgraded** to the latest version? Rather than downloading it separately from Maintenance Tool, and Migrating the Project to the Newer versions manually.

---

Like, currently I have Qt 6.2.2, and I want to upgrade to Qt 6.2.3 (as, there's a fix I need). To update, I have to download the whole package from the Maintenance Tool, do all the selections all over again, and migrate my existing projects to the newer version.
Is there exist a convenient way? As Visual Studio provides.

Answer (score 1):

The way i do is conan package menager. You have [Qt](https://conan.io/center/qt) and other great packages there. You can check https://www.qt.io/blog/installing-qt-via-conan-package-manager how to setup or use some existing starter project with it like https://github.com/cpp-best-practices/cpp_starter_project/blob/master/cmake/Conan.cmake#L28 or maybe even https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan when you setup your project with conan changing version required you to change for example `qt/6.2.2` to `qt/6.2.3` and rerun CMake if you using it of course. It will require you to setup conan in your project and that can be tricky. But after that you will see all pros of using conan. Worked great for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! After some testing, and failures, it worked!